# Error in updating records using XML string

Tags: sql, xml, stored-procedures

I am getting error in updating columns using XML but don't know where is the problem. Please guide me to get the rid out of it..
This is part of the code for my stored procedure

```
IF(@Mode='UPDATE_TABLE')
BEGIN
    ;WITH XmlData AS 
        (
            SELECT
                NDS.DT.value('(ClaimExpenseID)[1]', 'int') AS 'ClaimExpenseID',
                NDS.DT.value('(ClaimID)[1]', 'int') AS 'ClaimID',
                NDS.DT.value('(POrderID)[1]', 'int') AS 'POrderID',
                NDS.DT.value('(SiteID)[1]', 'int') AS 'SiteID',
                NDS.DT.value('(FromDate)[1]', 'datetime') AS 'FromDate',
                NDS.DT.value('(ToDate)[1]', 'datetime') AS 'ToDate',
                NDS.DT.value('(PearticularID)[1]', 'int') AS 'ParticularID',
                NDS.DT.value('(Description)[1]', 'varchar(200)') AS 'Description',
                NDS.DT.value('(SubmitAmount)[1]', 'int') AS 'SubmittedAmount',
                NDS.DT.value('(CreatedDate)[1]', 'datetime') AS 'CreatedDate',
                NDS.DT.value('(ApprovedAmount)[1]', 'int') AS 'ApprovedAmount',
                NDS.DT.value('(ApprovedDate)[1]', 'datetime') AS 'ApprovedDate',
                NDS.DT.value('(Remark)[1]', 'varchar(300)') AS 'Remark',
                NDS.DT.value('(ApprovedBy)[1]', 'int') AS 'ApprovedBy',                 
                NDS.DT.value('(RowInfo)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS 'RowInfo'

            FROM 
                @xmlString.nodes('/NewDataSet/DataTable') AS NDS(DT)

        )

        MERGE INTO dbo.ClaimExpenseTRS CET
        USING XmlData x ON CET.ClaimExpenseID = x.ClaimExpenseID
        WHEN MATCHED AND x.RowInfo = 'UPDATE'
           THEN 
             UPDATE SET 
                CET.ClaimID=x.ClaimID,  
                CET.CreatedDate=x.CreatedDate,
                CET.POrderID=x.POrderID,
                CET.SiteID=x.SiteID,
                CET.FromDate=x.FromDate,
                CET.ToDate=x.ToDate,
                CET.ParticularID=x.ParticularID,
                CET.Description=x.Description,
                CET.SubmittedAmount=x.SubmittedAmount,
                CET.ApprovedAmount=x.ApprovedAmount,
                CET.Remarks=x.Remark,
                CET.ApproveBy=x.ApprovedBy,
                CET.ApprovedDate=x.ApprovedDate

      WHEN MATCHED AND x.RowInfo = 'DELETE'AND CET.ClaimExpenseID = x.ClaimExpenseID
           THEN DELETE 

        WHEN NOT MATCHED AND x.RowInfo = 'NEW'
           THEN 
              INSERT(ClaimID, CreatedDate, POrderID, SiteID,FromDate,ToDate,ParticularID,                 Description,SubmittedAmount,ApprovedAmount,Remarks,ApproveBy,ApprovedDate)
              VALUES(x.ClaimID,x.CreatedDate,x.POrderID,x.SiteID,x.FromDate,x.ToDate,x. 
              ParticularID,x.Description,x.SubmittedAmount,x.ApprovedAmount,x.Remark,x.                   ApprovedBy,x.ApprovedDate);
END
```

This is my XML script..

```
<NewDataSet>
  <DataTable>
    <ClaimExpenseID>14</ClaimExpenseID>
    <ClaimID>10</ClaimID>
    <CreatedDate>2011-09-14T02:00:00+05:30</CreatedDate>
    <POrderID>11</POrderID>
    <SiteID>1</SiteID>
    <FromDate>2011-09-18T00:00:00+05:30</FromDate>
    <ToDate>2011-09-20T00:00:00+05:30</ToDate>
    <NoOfDays>2</NoOfDays>
    <ParticularID>1</ParticularID>
    <Description>Restaurant123 </Description>
    <SubmittedAmount>200</SubmittedAmount>
    <Month>September</Month>
    <Year>2011</Year>
    <POrderNo>UNINOR</POrderNo>
    <SiteName>ALKAPURI</SiteName>
    <ParticulerName>Food</ParticulerName>
    <RowInfo>UPDATE</RowInfo>
    <TableRowIndex>0</TableRowIndex>
  </DataTable>
  <DataTable>
     <ClaimExpenseID>15</ClaimExpenseID>
    <ClaimID>10</ClaimID>
    <CreatedDate>2011-09-15T00:00:00+05:30</CreatedDate>
    <POrderID>10</POrderID>
    <SiteID>2</SiteID>
    <FromDate>2011-09-16T00:00:00+05:30</FromDate>
    <ToDate>2011-09-17T00:00:00+05:30</ToDate>
    <NoOfDays>1</NoOfDays>
    <ParticularID>2</ParticularID>
   <Description>bus</Description>
   <SubmittedAmount>100</SubmittedAmount>
   <Month>September</Month>
   <Year>2011</Year>
   <POrderNo>PO-00120</POrderNo>
   <SiteName>NIZAMPURA</SiteName>
   <ParticulerName>Traveling123</ParticulerName>
   <RowInfo>UNCHANGED</RowInfo>
   <TableRowIndex>1</TableRowIndex>
 </DataTable>
```

When I run this script, it stores NULL for particularID and for SubmittedAmount both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `PearticularID` to `ParticularID` and `SubmitAmount` to `SubmittedAmount`.

```
SELECT
    NDS.DT.value('(ClaimExpenseID)[1]', 'int') AS 'ClaimExpenseID',
    NDS.DT.value('(ClaimID)[1]', 'int') AS 'ClaimID',
    NDS.DT.value('(POrderID)[1]', 'int') AS 'POrderID',
    NDS.DT.value('(SiteID)[1]', 'int') AS 'SiteID',
    NDS.DT.value('(FromDate)[1]', 'datetime') AS 'FromDate',
    NDS.DT.value('(ToDate)[1]', 'datetime') AS 'ToDate',
    NDS.DT.value('(ParticularID)[1]', 'int') AS 'ParticularID',
    NDS.DT.value('(Description)[1]', 'varchar(200)') AS 'Description',
    NDS.DT.value('(SubmittedAmount)[1]', 'int') AS 'SubmittedAmount',
    NDS.DT.value('(CreatedDate)[1]', 'datetime') AS 'CreatedDate',
    NDS.DT.value('(ApprovedAmount)[1]', 'int') AS 'ApprovedAmount',
    NDS.DT.value('(ApprovedDate)[1]', 'datetime') AS 'ApprovedDate',
    NDS.DT.value('(Remark)[1]', 'varchar(300)') AS 'Remark',
    NDS.DT.value('(ApprovedBy)[1]', 'int') AS 'ApprovedBy',                 
    NDS.DT.value('(RowInfo)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS 'RowInfo'

FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/NewDataSet/DataTable') AS NDS(DT)
```